# How to make a Laravel Eloquent Resource include filter parameters in the links?

Tags: json, laravel, api, eloquent, resources

We're experimenting a bit with the query builder by Spatie, and I would like to return a Resource collection.

Unfortunately, when you add filters to the request, these are not sent back as part of the first, last, previous and next links of the reply.

this is our code (just an example with a very simple mode `ExchangeRate`:

```
class ExchangeRateController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
       return \App\Resources\ExchangeRate::collection(
         QueryBuilder::for(ExchangeRate::class)
            ->allowedFilters(
                Filter::exact('currency'), 
                Filter::scope('valid-on')
            )
            ->paginate());
    }
}
```

When we call `GET /api/exchangerates`, we're getting 3 pages of 15 records each.  When we call `GET /api/exchangerates?filter[currency]=USD`we're getting 1 page with just 1 record.  This is all fine, but the links in the json response don't get correct links.

Without the filter, we're getting the following links:

```
"links": {
  "first": "https://example.com/api/exchangerates?page=1",
  "last": "https://example.com/api/exchangerates?page=3",
  "prev": null,
  "next": "https://example.com/api/exchangerates?page=2"
}
```

With the filter, we're getting the following links in the response:

```
"links": {
  "first": "https://example.com/api/exchangerates?page=1",
  "last": "https://example.com/api/exchangerates?page=1",
  "prev": null,
  "next": null
}
```

So, it gets its pagination done right, but the filters are not included in the links, which I believe is incorrect (the client should be able to trust those links to fetch the *next page* of its currently selected dataset...)

Is there anyway that we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be the responsibility of the package. Laravel pagination does not preserve query strings in the links. It seems this is the behavior since 4.2. See [this.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19441)

You could possibly do it with the following though:

```
class ExchangeRateController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        return \App\Resources\ExchangeRate::collection(
            QueryBuilder::for(ExchangeRate::class)
                ->allowedFilters(
                    Filter::exact('currency'), 
                    Filter::scope('valid-on')
                )
                ->paginate()
                ->appends($request->input('currency', 'valid-on'))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: huh?  it makes no sense to me really - why do you say it's not the package's responsibility?  I'm querying a resource with some parameters, and it returns the links for the different pages; if a client were to request those links, it would simply return entirely different information...

Comment: You are calling `paginate()` which extends Laravel's Builder. See [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder/blob/master/src/QueryBuilder.php#L213) - I also don't see the package doing anything to add default filters. Maybe it should. That's debatable.

Comment: I think it should really.  Laravel's builder is what generates the pagination links; it should consider all resource parameters, not?  Why would Eloquent correctly apply the filters, but not consider them to generate the links.  It makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Since it is easy to just add the parameters you need with `appends()`, I would think the behavior is kept that way to stay flexible. You could always submit a PR to the library though to add default filters. It makes sense too :)

Comment: Knowing Laravel, it'll probably not make it, but I'm just thinking about making it manageable... I don't want to have to repeat that logic in each controller method again ;-)  THanks for your reply though!

Comment: You're welcome. I meant to Spatie's library though. It shouldn't be that hard to append it to the paginator :)

Comment: The spatie package doesn't have pagination logic in it - it just creates the Query, but pagination falls back to the Eloquent support...  I would prefer it to be "solved" in Laravel core itself; if it works there, it works for all packages relying on it ;-)

Comment: Again, debatable imo. Filters in Spatie are being explicitly passed, which means, they could probably be more trusted. Well, since it extends and overrides the `paginate()` method of Laravel's query builder, it could be done. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ;-)  Have a nice day!